# cocoa - referencing a method on the parent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I had a method on my main view controller named "calculateThis".

This method was run, obviously, as

```
int newValue = [self calculateThis:myVariable];
```

when I run it from inside the view controller.

Then I created a static class and I need to run this method from there.

How do I reference this method from that class using just relative references, as super, superview, delegate, etc. I cannot use the class name defined on the delegate because this static class is used in several apps of mine.

I need to go up in the hierarchy, I imagine one level, and access the method there...

thanks.

Comment: What is a static class? You mean a subclass? You say "parent" as though It's a subclass of your other class, but then say it's independent of that class. What's the actual relationship here?

Comment: a class that do not needs to initiate an instance... in my case it is a generic class where I put zillions of methods I use in all my apps, so I simply drag this to any project I start and have instantly several methods ready to use.

Comment: I am not sure... I think it is the parent something of where I am... let's assume I am in a regular class...

Comment: My question is this: when I am on the view controller I use "[self..." to call any method, but How do I reference this "self" from that class... I imagine this as having to go up one level in the hierarchy... like typing "../runThisShell.sh" on the console... ".." meaning go up one level... how do I do that on objective-c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your utility methods in a category on NSObject or related subclasses of NSObject. 
Which you have done.

Adding (id)sender to your method will work. Then your method can reference the object that called it. Something like this.

```
+(int)calculateThis:(id)sender userInfo:(id)info;
```

then your call becomes.

```
int newValue = [NSObject calculateThis:self userInfo:myVariable];
```

Comment: my methods are on a category of NSObject. All them are marked with +, like in +(void)...  So I can use them without instancing an object...my problem is how I access the class which called the method from within the method.

Comment: welcome. it occurred to me that you should be able to use the following statement to make it more clear in your code that you are using a class method defined in your category.

   int newValue = [NSObject calculateThis:self userInfo:myVariable];

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to create a class that you can use without initializing it, that's possible using class methods. For instance, if I want to make a class called `MyClass` with a `doSomethingWith:` method, I would define the following:

In `MyClass.h`:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

}

+(void)doSomethingWith:(id)thisObject;

@end
```

In `MyClass.m`:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

+(void)doSomethingWith:(id)thisObject
{
    // Your code goes here.
}

@end
```

To reference this method in another class, you can use the class object for `MyClass` like so:

```
[MyClass doSomethingWith:@"Hello, World!"];
```

This isn't really a typical Cocoa or Cocoa Touch design pattern, but can be handy for things like calculations.

Comment: This should be a singleton under Cocoa convention. A class that's never instantiated sounds like it should just be a collection of functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the *superclass*? If so, you use `[super ...]`.